# Parsing custom field type

Tags: 2007, custom-field-types, xml

I developed a custom field type for List, now I am trying to get list data using SharePoint list web services in "K2 workflow" I can get all fields values except this custom field type as I am not sure if I need to parse it to what type.

e.g. if its a string we use

```
childNode.Attributes[columnName].Value;
```

for double we use

```
double d = float.NaN;                                   
double.TryParse(childNode.Attributes[columnID].Value, out d);
ID = d;
```

Wonder what it gonna be like to parse a custom field type whose format is 1.1.1 and its class is inheriting from "SPFieldText" but when I try to prase it like string, it gives me Object reference not set..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get custom field values just like default ones but I was confused at that time,

```
childNode.Attributes[customColumnName].Value;
```

however its recommended to check if field exists before getting its value as otherwise it will break your code,

Hope it helps if someone else come across same issue :)